# Unable to use GPIO PWM when multiple threads are available

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gpio, pwm

I am working on a project which continuously waits for an user input on a [screen](https://nextion.itead.cc/). Once a user input was detected a [servo](https://aws.robu.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/IMG_0521.jpg) mechanism needs to open and then close. The whole solution is written in such a way that there's one main thread and few others that are forked from the main one as follows:

[image]

The problem with this setup is the this one:

1. If I execute only the operations handled in the main thread -> **BoxOpeningManager.py** works as expected. It opens and closes the servo.
2. If I execute once an operation handled in the main thread and then operation handled in the forked thread, the next time I try to execute operation on the main thread **BoxOpeningManager.py** is not working. No error, no nothing. It is just not opening the servo. I need to restart the program.
3. If first I execute an operation handled in the forked thread and then try to execute one handled in the main thread, main thread is again not working.

The long story short, every time I execute something on the forked thread, I can not use the **BoxOpeningManager.py** in the main thread anymore.

Here is the code of both scripts:

```
from servoManager import ServoManager
from proximitySensorManager import ProximitySensorManager
from configurationWrapping import GlobalConfigurationWrapper
from loggingManager import Logger

import time

class BoxOpeningManager():

    def __init__(self):
        self.configuration = GlobalConfigurationWrapper()
        self.timeToKeepTheBoxOpen = self.configuration.box_time_to_keep_the_box_open()
        self.logger = Logger()

        self.servoManager = ServoManager()      
        self.proximitySensorManager = ProximitySensorManager();

    def start_box_opening_procedure(self):
        try:
            self.servoManager.open()

            t_end = time.time() + (int)(self.timeToKeepTheBoxOpen)
            while time.time() < t_end:
                continue

            while True:
                if not self.proximitySensorManager.object_in_front() :         
                    self.servoManager.close()
                    break;
                else :
                    time.sleep(1)
        except BaseException as e:
            self.logger.log_critical('<BoxOpeningManager.start_box_opening_procedure> => ' + str(e))
```

Servo manager:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

from patternImplementations import Singleton
from loggingManager import Logger

class ServoManager():
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

    __OUTPUT_GPIO_PIN_NUMBER = 12

    def __init__(self):
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)#Numbers GPIOs by physical location
        GPIO.setup(self.__OUTPUT_GPIO_PIN_NUMBER, GPIO.OUT)

        self.pwm=GPIO.PWM(self.__OUTPUT_GPIO_PIN_NUMBER,50)
        self.pwm.start(0)

        self.logger = Logger()

    def open(self):
        try:
            self.__set_angle(13)
        except BaseException as e:
            self.logger.log_critical('<ServoManager.open> => ' + str(e))

    def close(self):
        try:
            self.__set_angle(185)
        except BaseException as e:
            self.logger.log_critical('<ServoManager.close> => ' + str(e))

    def __set_angle(self, angle):
        duty = (angle/18 + 2)

        GPIO.output(self.__OUTPUT_GPIO_PIN_NUMBER, True)
        self.pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(duty)

        sleep(1)

        GPIO.output(self.__OUTPUT_GPIO_PIN_NUMBER, False)
        self.pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
```

Comment: I assume `def start_box_opening_procedure(self):` is the `Thread` workload?

Comment: @stovfl No, it is not. There's a completely different file (being thread executed) which uses BoxOpeningManager.py

Comment: Where are `class BoxOpeningManager():` instantiated? **Once** or **per `Thread`**?

Comment: @stovfl in the forked thread context -> on each use case a new instance of BoxOpeningManager() gets created. In the main thread context there's a single instance of BoxOpeningManager() for the whole lifecycle of the app.

Comment: *"on each use case a new instance of BoxOpeningManager() gets created"*: I suggest not to doing so. There should **only one** instance exists in the whole app. The usage of `start_box_opening_procedure(self):` should be `Thread  locked`, means another `Thread` have to wait until `start_box_opening_procedure(self)` has finished.

Comment: I am pretty much sure start_box_opening_procedure(self) never gets called simultaneously from both forked thread and main thread. So, I don't think there's some kind of racing issue or deadlocking. I'd rather say that the forked thread somehow takes a complete hold on the ServoManager and never gives back the access to other threads.

Comment: *"the forked thread ... hold on the ServoManager and never gives back the access to other threads"*: Do you use `Thread locking` elsewhere? We have reached our comments limit, open a chat if you want to continue.

Comment: @stovfl I am not using `Thread locking` anywhere. I just create worker threads as follows: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread  

Inside of one of my threads I create a new instance of BoxOpeningManager every time. This is what I call `forked thread`.